# Not able to show the context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, contextmenu

I am having table as::

```
<table>
    <tbody role="rowgroup">
    <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="969dc7e1-0267-46c5-b9ec-b576ba97efc8" role="row">
        <td class="CIDNoInvoiceNo" data-consolidatedinvoicedispatchid="173" data-customerid="548" oncontextmenu="GetTemplateDetails(this,548);return false;" role="gridcell" id="DispatchManagement_active_cell">
            Test
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Where on the cell(with classname=CIDNoInvoiceNo) of table, I want to use the context menu.

I have given some attempts like ::

```
function GetTemplateDetails(self,CustomerID)
    {
            var ConsolidatedInvoiceDispatchID = $(self).attr('data-consolidatedinvoicedispatchid');

            var CurrentRowID = $(self).closest('tr').attr("data-uid");

            //POST AJAX to get Template Details
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: rootUrl("Dispatch/GetConsolidatedInvoiceDispatchDocuments"),
                data: { ConsolidatedInvoiceDispatchID: ConsolidatedInvoiceDispatchID, CustomerID: CustomerID },
                success: function (data) {
                    var dataObjectForItems = [];

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        dataObjectForItems["data" + i] = {   name: data[i].Description };
                    }

                    $.contextMenu({
                        selector: "tr[data-uid="+ CurrentRowID +"]>.CIDNoInvoiceNo",
                        callback: function (key, options) {
                            var m = "clicked: " + options.items[key].name;
                            window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
                        },
                        items: dataObjectForItems
                    });

                }
            });


            return false;

    }
```

using this I am getting context from server side but can't able to show data in right click.

Comment: Are there any errors in console? Does your `selector` selects what it should?

Comment: no there is no error

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin selector selects it properly.

Comment: What's the data object that comes back structured like? The `for loop` where you massage the data looks a bit funky... Specifically this part `dataObjectForItems["data" + i]`

Comment: data comes in Json format with length more than 2

Comment: Here's a demo (I've mocked the ajax call) which seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/nfhg5ggt/ - I think pebbl is correct. Either use an object literal or re-work your array.

Comment: Updated to object literal (instead of an array literal): http://jsfiddle.net/nfhg5ggt/1/ (which seems to verify pebbl's answer)

Comment: Please look at http://jsfiddle.net/nfhg5ggt/2/ where second row doesn't work.

Comment: You're missing the `data-uid` attribute from the second row.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nfhg5ggt/3/ (the parent `tr`)

Comment: @JackPattishall Thanks a lot!! http://jsfiddle.net/nfhg5ggt/6/ just have a look to this.

Seems to be working fine

Comment: post your answer so that I can mark it as answered & will be good for others future reference.

Answer (score 0):

According to [jQuery contextMenu's documentation/demo](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html), it expects an object to be passed as the items property. You are currently passing an array, on which you are trying to create string keys... Arrays should not be used this way in JavaScript, they should be reserved for numerical indexes only, and linear indexes starting at zero if you want to be pedantic about optimisation. You should switch to using an Object instead if you wish to have string keys.

so rather than using:

```
var dataObjectForItems = [];
```

You should use:

```
var dataObjectForItems = {};
```

An example to illustrate why you can't set string keys to an array:

```
var a = [];

a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
a[2] = 3;

a['string'] = 4;

console.log(a);
```

The output of the above would be:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

And you will find that `'string'` has been added as a property, rather than an element in the array. You can confirm this by logging the array's length, which would still only be 3, rather than 4.

[Example Fiddle illustrating string keys on arrays](http://jsfiddle.net/gwrLjeqq/)

However, if you switch to using an object, every key you add is treated as (or converted to) a string. This seems to be what jQuery contentMenu expects; so that every menu item has a named identifier, and is what your code needs in order to set string keys.

### But hang on a moment...

> if the keys are being added as properties, surely that's the same as an object anyway?

If jQuery contextMenu was using a `for i in` loop to navigate the items then yes, using an array or an object would make no difference (as long as the array itself was devoid of actual elements). It is not a good idea to rely on this possibility though, because you are essentially abusing an array. However, this is not what is happening in this instance, and because we are talking about a jQuery plug-in — obviously the plug-in is making use of `jQuery.each` on line 937.

```
// create contextMenu items
$.each(opt.items, function(key, item){
```

This will detect that `opt.items` is an array, and treat it accordingly, meaning it will only step through the array elements and not the properties; which for your array `dataObjectForItems` means there is nothing to step through.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760508/add-multiple-items-to-context-menu

Comment: @Ratatouille ~ Yes, and how does that change anything? Both users answering your question are using objects, rather than arrays, which is what you should do.